# Laravel collective form and foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I want to connect my dropdown select form with database, currentli I have sth like this:

```
                 @foreach( $clients as $client)
                    {!! Form::select('connected_with',
                     ['name' => $client->name . $client->surname
                      ]) !!}
                    @endforeach
```

And this is my controller:

```
        $clients = Client::all();

        return view('report_create')->with('clients', $clients);
```

and i get much fields. I want only one with items from db. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create select list of clients, use `pluck()`:

```
$clients = Client::pluck('full_name', 'id');
return view('report_create')->with('clients', $clients);
```

To make it work, you'll also need to [define an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in the `Client` model:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->name.' '.$this->surname;
}
```

Then just create the list:

```
{!! Form::select('connected_with', $clients) !!}
```